# C# change console encoding error (bad descriptor)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, encoding, console

Today i run Visual Studio and open my project, that i not opened about 5 months.
And running test (it was be OK) invoke `IOException` with additional information: "Bad descriptor".

It was in this line:

```
var defaultConsoleEncoding = Console.InputEncoding;
Console.InputEncoding = TryGetEncoding("UTF-8");  // <--- There is error
...
public static Encoding TryGetEncoding(string encoding)
    {
        try
        {
            return Encoding.GetEncoding(encoding);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            Logger.WarnAndPrint($"Can't using {encoding} encoding. Fallback to utf-8");
            return Encoding.UTF8;
        }
    }
```

All my tests were OK, but now all fails with that error. I never chage code in project. And i try many encodings - nothing work.

What's the problem?

P.S. This is stack trace

```
System.IO.IOException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147024890
  Message=Неверный дескриптор.

  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       в System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
       в System.Console.set_InputEncoding(Encoding value)
       в PasswordListGenerator.Substitutions.Substitution.Process() в C:\GITHUB\passwordlistgenerator\PasswordListGenerator\PasswordListGenerator\Substitutions\Substitution.cs:строка 89
       в PasswordListGeneratorTest.SubstitutionTests.SkipManySymbols_ShouldReturnSubstitutions() в C:\GITHUB\passwordlistgenerator\PasswordListGenerator\PasswordListGeneratorTest\SubstitutionTests.cs:строка 588
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Out of interest, do you get the same error if you just change your code to `Console.InputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;`? (There's no real need for your `TryGetEncoding` method here, I suspect.)

Comment: @JonSkeet i wonder hy, but yes! It's same error when i use just `Console.InputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;`!

Comment: Recheck my git steps, i found, that the problem appear just in moment, when i add this encoding change for console. Is this right way to change console encoding?

Comment: My guess is that it's the right way to change the input encoding, but that it can't be set to UTF-8. You're sure you want to change the *input* encoding, right?

Comment: @JonSkeet right. I need definetly *input* encoding. But it seems like in tests no metter, what type of encoding set. Coz i delete *change encoding code*, then try input from console "©" symbol and it's work correct...
Wonder, if it's really need to change input encoding if it's work fine without it...

Comment: When typing into the console it might now matter - it may matter more if you're piping from one process to another. (I don't know for sure.)